# I need to join an integer and a character as a single string in C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have a project that reads data from a text file and sores the data into a linked list of structures. After I read in the data I can print the data and it is all fine. I then call an external function to add datd to the file, at this time the pointer to the first element gets set to NULL eventhough I do not tell it to in code. After I add the data, only what was added is displayed.  I need some advice.

```
struct residentRec {
    string SSN;
    char firstInit;
    string lastName;
    string phoneNo;
    char phoneType;
}; // end resident definition

struct residentNode {
      residentRec res;
      residentNode* nextRes;
};

residentNode* newData(residentNode* &first, residentNode* &last,residentNode* resList);

int main ()
{
    residentNode* resList = NULL;
    residentNode* first;
    residentNode* last;

    resList = newData(first, last, resList);

    return;
}

residentNode* newData(residentNode* &first, residentNode* &last, residentNode* resList)
{
    return(resList);
}
```

Comment: You should use `std::list` from the `<list>` header so you don't have to worry about this sort of stuff and can return to more important matters.

Comment: There's not much we can deduce from the code you posted. It does nothing.

Comment: If this is homework, it should have the homework tag.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're asking, but I'm going to answer the question you have in the title.

You can use the `stringstream` class:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

stringstream s;
s << 'a' << 3;
string str = s.str();
//str is "a3"
```